# Previous and Next Page is Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pagination

I am building a site on my main page. I'm grabbing some data from JSON, and displaying it all. It includes a bunch of albums with fields like album title, album artist, etc. When I click on one album, it sends another call to the api via angular and grabs the data for just that album and displays it.

On this page, I want to have ‘previous’ and ‘next’ buttons to display the previous albums data and the next albums

I'm not sure how to do this

this is the albums/ main page ...

```
<section class="container-fluid music-section pad-bottom-60 pad-top-20 pad-top-30-l">
    <div class="clear album-collection">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="albums in music">
                <a href="/music/{{albums.slug}}" class="col-12 col-1-5-xl col-1-4-l col-1-2-m album-collection__cover transition">
                    <img ng-src='{{albums.better_featured_image.source_url}}'>
                    <div class="album-overlay">
                        <div class="album-overlay__text-container animate">
                            <div class="album-overlay-text">
                                <span>JMP-{{albums.acf.album_cat_no}}</span>
                                <br><br>
                                <h3>{{albums.title.rendered}}</h3>
                                <br><br>
                                <span>View Album</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

this is one album page :

```
<section class="container-fluid music-album-section pad-bottom-60">
    <div class='clear row'>
        <div class="col-2-5-l col-12 music-album__left-section">
            <img class="pad-top-60-l pad-top-20 animate fade-in-left-big" ng-src='{{album.better_featured_image.source_url}}'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2-l push-1-l col-12 music-album__right-section pad-top-60-l pad-top-20 pad-bottom-50 animate fade-in-big">
            <a class="back-to-all-music-link pad-bottom-50" href="/music/"><img src="../img/left-arrow.png">All Albums</a>
            <span class="animate fade-in-left-big track-numbers">{{album.acf.album_track_number}} Tracks</span>
            <span class="animate fade-in-left-big catalogue-number">JMP-{{album.acf.album_cat_no}}</span>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-4-5-l pad-top-10">
                    <h1 class="animate fade-in-left-big music-album-title">{{album.title.rendered}}</h1>
                    <article class="pad-bottom-30 pad-top-10">
                        <p class="animate fade-in-left-big" ng-bind-html="album.content.rendered"></p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3-l col-1-2 pad-top-30-l pad-bottom-60-l pad-bottom-20">
                    <button class="animate fade-in-left-big button-primary button-primary__big">
                <img src= "./img/play-button.png">
                <span>Play Montage</span>
            </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3-l col-1-2 pad-top-30-l pad-bottom-60-l pad-bottom-20">
                    <button class="animate fade-in-left-big button-primary button-primary__big">
                        Listen &amp; download
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="next-previous-album-links pad-top-30-l pad-top-40-s pad-bottom-20">
                <a href="/music/"><img src="./img/left-arrow.png">Previous Album</a>
                <a href="/music/" class="right">Next Album<img src="./img/right-arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and my angular :

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'main.html',
            controller: 'Main'
        })
        .when('/music', {
            templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'music.php',
            controller: 'Music'
        })
        .when('/music/:slug/', {
            templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'album.html',
            controller: 'Album'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

})

.controller('Main', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/').success(function (res) {
        $scope.posts = res;
    });
})

.controller('Music', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/post_music').success(function (res) {
        $rootScope.music = res;
        console.log($scope.music)
    });
})

.controller('Album', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/post_music/?filter[name]=' + $routeParams.slug).success(function (res) {
        $scope.album = res[0];
    });
});
```